# Laravel eloquent: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string join query

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent

I am trying to get all the vehicles that dont have a booking for the selected dates:

```
 $bookings = Booking::all();
 $vehicles = Vehicle::all();

 $selectedStart = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i',  $request['start']);
 $selectedEnd =  Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i',  $request['end']);


 $availableVehicles = $vehicles->join('bookings', function ($join){
        $join->on('vehicles.id', '=', 'bookings.vehicle_id')
            ->where([
                    ['bookings.start', '<',$selectedStart],
                    ['bookings.end', '<', $selectedStart]
                ])->orWhere([
                    ['bookings.start', '>',$selectedEnd],
                    ['bookings.end', '>', $selectedEnd]
                ]);
  })->get();
```

But I get the following error:

> Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `query()` method here instead of `all()` method because `all()` method get rows from database and store into collection..

```
$bookings = Booking::query();
$vehicles = Vehicle::query();

$selectedStart = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i',  $request['start']);
$selectedEnd =  Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i',  $request['end']);


$availableVehicles = $vehicles->join('bookings', function ($join) use ($selectedStart,$selectedEnd){
        $join->on('vehicles.id', '=', 'bookings.vehicle_id')
            ->where([
                    ['bookings.start', '<',$selectedStart],
                    ['bookings.end', '<', $selectedStart]
                ])->orWhere([
                    ['bookings.start', '>',$selectedEnd],
                    ['bookings.end', '>', $selectedEnd]
                ]);
})->get();
```

Comment: looks promising but I get this: undefined variable $selectedStart

Comment: function ($join) use ($selectedStart, $selectedEnd)

Answer (score 1):

The answer marked as correct is technically correct, but your code could be tidied up and improved upon:

```php
$availableVehicles = Vehicle::query()
    ->join('bookings', function ($join) use ($request){
        $selectedStart = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i',  $request['start']);
        $selectedEnd   = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i',  $request['end']);

        $join->on('vehicles.id', '=', 'bookings.vehicle_id')
            ->where([
                ['bookings.start', '<',$selectedStart],
                ['bookings.end', '<', $selectedStart]
            ])->orWhere([
                ['bookings.start', '>',$selectedEnd],
                ['bookings.end', '>', $selectedEnd]
            ]);
    })
    ->get();
```

Your `$bookings` and `$vehicles` variables aren't relevant at this point unless they're used in code you've not included.